# Very simply: setProvider is not a function

Tags: web3js, interfaces

I have a [very simple contract already deployed to the kovan network](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x8b5fe00cf3cb34caa9c3e968d5b4d96f927d3495#code)

I want to create a very simple web3 interface, so I'm following the truffle webpack metacoin example with the following app.js

```
import "../stylesheets/app.css";
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'

var abi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":
[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setvalue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"value","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]
var contractAddress = "0x8b5fe00cf3cb34caa9c3e968d5b4d96f927d3495"; //on Kovan
var simple = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi);

window.App = { 
  start: function() {
    var self = this;
    simple.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
    self.refreshBalance();
  },

  refreshBalance: function() {
    var self = this;
    var meta;
    simple.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      meta = instance;
      return meta.value.call();
    }).then(function(value) {
      var balance_element = document.getElementById("balance");
      balance_element.innerHTML = value.valueOf();
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  },

  updateValue: function() {
    var self = this;
    var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
    this.setStatus("Initiating transaction... (please wait)");
    var meta;
    simple.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      meta = instance;
      return meta.setvalue(amount);
    }).then(function() {
      self.refreshBalance();
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
  App.start();
});
```

But I'm always getting the message

> simple.setProvider is not a function

and

> simple.deployed is not a function

Any help greatly appreciated.  I'm using truffle-init-webpack@0.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating the contract like this:

```
var abi = [...]; // a valid abi
var contractAddress = 0x.......... // the address where the matching contract is deployed

      var MyTruffleContract = contract({
        abi: abi
      })
      MyTruffleContract.setProvider(this.web3.currentProvider);
      console.log(MyTruffleContract);

      MyTruffleContract
      .at(contractAddress)
      .then(instance =>{
        instance.totalSupply({
          from: this.account
        })
        .then(value =>{
          console.log("Total Supply:",this.web3.fromWei(value, "ether").toString(10));
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      })
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain why deployed() doesn't work but .at(contractAddress) does?